# How to get "raw" href contents in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anchor, href, relative-url

I am trying to write a GreaseMonkey script in which I want to find all of the links that are relative links.  It seemed to me that the way to do that would be to match the contents of href against `/^https?:///`.

But I find that when I access the anchor's href attribute, it's always normalized or cooked into a form that contains "http".  That is, if the HTML contains:

```
<a id="rel" href="/relative/link">inner</a>
```

accessing

```
document.getElementById("rel").href
```

returns

```
http://example.com/relative/link
```

How can I access the raw data in the href attribute?

Alternately, is there a better way to find relative links?

Comment: Have you tried element.getAttribute("href")?

Comment: @Ionut, why'd you not add that as an answer?

Comment: J-P, the question was a bit unclear at the beginning. At the time I posted my comment it was not clear whether he tried using the `getAttribute` method or just the `href` property.

Comment: Yeah, I spazzed out on the code.  Sorry, Ionut.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try the [`getAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE7 seems to return the fully qualified URL even with this approach.

Comment: For those interested, [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280487/2518231) answer has more information as to why `.href` and `.getAttibute('href')` return different values on most browsers.

Answer (score 38):

Typical.  I figured it out myself almost immediately after posting the question.

instead of:

```
anchor.href
```

use:

```
anchor.getAttribute("href")
```

Of course, it took me longer to type in this answer than it took everyone else to answer it.  (Damn, you people are fast.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet you could run to test.

```
const anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (let anchor of anchors) {
  let hrefFullPath = anchor.href;
  let hrefRelativePath = anchor.attributes.href.value;

  console.log('hrefFullPath', hrefFullPath);
  console.log('hrefRelativePath', hrefRelativePath);
}
```

Let's say, you are at `http://localhost:4200`, and this is your document as you have shown in the question.

```
<a id="rel" href="/relative/link">inner</a>
```

This anchor's attribute value of `href` is:

```
document.getElementById('rel').attributes.href.value => /relative/link
```

And anchor's `href` value is:

```
document.getElementById('rel').href =>  http://localhost:4200/relative/link
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Get the link dom and add attributes for same and append the actual link to same.

```
var hrefUrl = 'https://www.google.com/';

const link: HTMLLinkElement = dom?.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
link.setAttribute('id', 'seo');
dom?.head?.appendChild(link);
dom?.getElementById('seo')?.setAttribute('href', hrefUrl);

// working
```

Hope this will work for dynamic links that to append for each dynamic pages under js / ts.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.