# How to get full anchor href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get “raw” href contents in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript)

Sometimes you write in your code relative paths to your files, so in the code the href attribute value could be `somefile.php` yet when clicking of course the anchor would send you to `http://www.yourdomain.com/somefiles.php`

Now my question is could I somehow obtain the full href of an anchor?

When using `$(anchor).attr("href")` you only get the relative path.

Comment: It's not, Matt here gave the working solution which is different from what presented in that link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`element.href` will get the entire href

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/acX4s/2/)

**EDIT:**

I'll quote something from [jQuery's website](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) here:

> The .prop() method should be used for boolean attributes/properties
>   and for properties which do not exist in html (such as
>   window.location). All other attributes (ones you can see in the html)
>   can and should continue to be manipulated with the .attr() method.

Since `.attr()` gets the actual value typed in the attribute, as it probably used the native `getAttribute()`, the proper way to do this would be to get the native javascript element, and then use the native `element.href` which will get the href including the domain and pathname etc.

Comment: But i'm not trying to get the attribute from within the event.

Comment: `document.getElementById('elementID').href` or `$(anchor)[0].href` will do that, as all you need is the plain JS object, not the jQuery object.

Comment: Oh i get it now. thanks i guess i've became too dependant on jQuery.

Comment: @eric.itzhak That's why it's a duplicate. Your asking for a jquery solution when plain javascript works just fine

Comment: Not only that, but `href` is an attribute not a property, so the `prop()` method is'nt really intended to be used that way -> [**link**](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/), even if it works as of now there is no guarantee that prop() will continue to work with the href **attribute**!

Comment: Here is a fiddle I needed to make to convince myself about all this: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/J9bWf/show

Answer (score 20):

You can use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(anchor).prop("href")
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5FT3a/1/):

```
console.log($("a").prop("href")); //http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/sth
console.log($("a").attr("href")); //sth
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery `prop` function.

for testing try following codes in your console for this page;

```
$("a:eq(6)").prop("href")
$("a:eq(6)").attr("href")
```

and for more information you can search for html attribute and property.