# How to get the exact href value only without their domain?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble in getting the exact value of href only. Here is the code:

```
Link:
<a href="monthly"></a>

Script:
'a': function(target, process){
    if(process == "stripe"){
        document.location.href = "/accounts/stripe/payment"+target[0].href;
    }else{
        ......
    }
},
```

If I run this the output will be:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/stripe/paymenthttp://localhost:8000/monthly/
```

Notice that the localhost is duplicating. How to get only the "monthly" in href without that localhost? I try target only but it's undefined. I try target[1] but it's not working.

Comment: Try `target[0].pathname`

Comment: Can you post your answer so that I can vote for it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little known (maybe) fact that most browsers convert Anchor node elements into Location objects as well.  So you can access all parts available to Location too;

```
 document.location.href = "/accounts/stripe/payment"+target[0].pathname;
```

Answer (score 18):

Try `target[0].getAttribute("href")` to get the literal attribute's content.