# add to current attribute value

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site where the content is being scraped from another site (both owned by same person). When it pulls in links, the href isn't formatted the way I need it to be, so I'm trying to preserve the original value and just add a slash to the beginning of it. I've gotten close, but can't get it to work properly. The current format is `href="like-this"`, but I need it to be `href="/like-this"`.

This what I've tried that came close:

```
$('.disamb li a').attr('href', function() {
    return '/' + this.href;
});
```

That returns the whole absolute url with a / at the very beginning. So I tried using `each()`:

```
$('.disamb li a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', '/'+this.href);
});
```

Same result. I tried a couple of other ways, but these two were the closest. How can I go about doing this without then running it through a replace function to strip it down to what I need? (that just seems sloppy)

Comment: What is an example of a URL and what you would like

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.disamb li a').attr('href', function(i, old) {
    return '/' + old;
});
```

The function receives two arguments, the index of the current element, and the current value of the attribute.

When you use `this.href`, you're getting the URL after the browser has canonicalized to a full, absolute URL, not the string value of the attribute.

Comment: Ah ok, that's good to know about using `this`. This worked exactly how I needed it to. Thank you! I knew I was close, but was going about it wrong.