# Java script get href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have the following code,

```
<ul class="post-buttons">
    <li>
        <a class="button icon-button thank-icon" title="Thank this post" href="./thank.php?f=12&p=249224"></a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

and on my javascript I have the following,

```
var ThankButton = $('div.thank-icon > a').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```

but on console log I get ThankButton not defined,
what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think its because there is no div element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript here is the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have javascript mistake

```
var ThankButton = $('ul.post-buttons li a.thank-icon').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any div in your code. You can try simply:

```
var ThankButton = $('a.thank-icon').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like,

```
var ThankButton = $('.thank-icon').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```

or

```
var ThankButton = $('ul li a').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```

or

```
var ThankButton = $('ul li a.thank-icon').attr('href');
console.log(ThankButton);
```