# Set origin when parsing HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, html-parsing

My JavaScript app retrieves a webpage by XHR then parses it like this:

```
        var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
        el.innerHTML = xml;

        var links = el.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
```

In the process, the links' `href` tags get reinterpreted as relative to *this* document, so I get links like `http://localhost:8000/download.zip`.

I tried hacking my way around it:

```
if (link.origin === document.origin) {
    link.href = link.href.replace(link.origin, h.url.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}
```

But that can't distinguish between `foo.org/bar` (foo.org/bar/download.zip) and `foo.org/bar.php` (foo.org/download.zip), and I don't really want to go down the rabbit hole of working out exactly what substitutions to perform.

I tried injecting either a `<base href=...>` or `<xml:base=xxx>` into the document, but that didn't work.

What am I missing? This seems like a common enough need?

I'm not using any jQuery or anything similar (and can't.)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript

Comment: Huh....that's very interesting. (Accessing `getAttribute('href')` instead of `.href`). That still doesn't quite solve the problem of resolving the relative link correctly for a path like `.../foo.php`.