# Get Anchor (a) Link from Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an Element Array retrieved using this line of code:

```
var listItems = ul[0].getElementsByTagName("li")
```

The output of

```
console.log(listItems[0].innerHTML)
```

gives me

```
<a class="view" href="https://www.notarealwebsite.com">See this cool link!</a>
```

How can I retrieve **only** the link (https://www.notarealwebsite.com) using **pure Javascript?**

I have tried the getAttribute("href") function to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to show how you were using `getAttribute` and it wasn't working, because that's literally the answer to your question. See [this duplicate question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550901/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward way to do this would be to get the `a` element inside of the `li` element, then access the `href` property off of that.

```
// using querySelector
const link = listItems[0].querySelector('a')

// or, using getElementsByTagName
const link = listItems[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]

console.log(link.href)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName