# How to get the relative path from a a.href property in Chrome's JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, anchor, href, relative-path

If `<a href="{relative path}">...</a>` is specified in a page's HTML the `a.href` property in Chrome's JavaScript returns an absolute path with the current `document.URL`.

I know I can extract the relative path portion from there with a combination of `replace()`, `substr()`, `indexOf()`, but I'd like to avoid this. Is there a property/function that returns exactly that what the HTML page developer defined as `{relative path}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get "raw" href contents in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550901/how-to-get-raw-href-contents-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute("href")`

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a").getAttribute("href"))
```

```html
<a id="a" href="/pages/index.html">Link</a>
```